# How does Facebook work with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How does Facebook work with AJAX? Thanks a lot!

**Before**

```
http://www.facebook.com/#/events.php
```

**Now**

```
http://www.facebook.com/?sk=events
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still doing the hash URLs and AJAX requests under the covers (though it fails fairly gracefully as well), it's just using some HTML5 features with history to push a different URL to your address bar.

If you view the site in an older browser that doesn't support this yet (everything besides Chrome at the moment) you'll still see the `#!/path` format ([for Google indexing](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)) on the URL, for example:

```
http://www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/?sk=events
```

Specifically it's using [`history.pushState()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) and [`history.replaceState()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-history-replacestate) added in HTML5, if the browser supports it to display another (direct) URL in your address bar.